# Threejs create optimized mesh from 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

What I want to achieve is creating a voxel environment, with a 2d array that holds all the positions for blocks.

Currently I'm doing this by using basic cube geometry, but it's really slow, and it has unnecessary faces on the sides of most of the cubes, and the bottoms.

How can I generate an optimized mesh? I'm assuming you would detect the neighbors and decide which faces to generate from there.

My data is an irregular shape, it looks like this:
[image]

The white areas are where there should be mesh, and then black areas are where there shouldn't be anything. (I have this converted into a 2d array of points)

I'm a bit lost on how to go about doing this. I looked at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_minecraft but thats for generating a square world, not one with holes and stuff in it.

So how would I go about doing this? Is there some code you guys could possibly post to help me out?

Any help is appreciated :)